# Association with remote system akka.tcp://sparkWorker has failed. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, akka, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

In my DSE spark node my system log frequently tells me this:

```
Association with remote system 
[akka.tcp://sparkWorker@10.47.183.109:41738] has failed, address is
 now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Association failed with 
[akka.tcp://sparkWorker@10.47.183.109:41738]].
```

I am not sure what this means. Is this a problem with my firewall? If so how to choose the port range? I don't know what the port range is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This the executor saying that it can't talk to anyone.  The port range isn't something you can open up exactly as it assigns a random port for communication. If all your nodes are on the same LAN do you still get this error?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can  change the `transport-failure-detector` settings to default.
Just like this [akka-user thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/X3xzpTCbEFs).

Comment: Ugh, referencing the prototypical mailing list thread (the very thing that SO was founded to get away from!) as almost the only thing in the answer? Surely you could do better.